# How to traverse abstract data structures to fully map a JSON tree in C++

Tags: c++, json, parsing, vector, tree

I've been working on a simple JSON parser that determines an input JSON string's  structure at runtime. I've tokenized the JSON and read the file into containers with respect to the JSON file's tree. I'm attempting to map the tree, and eventually provide an interface for modifying and outputting it.

I use a few container classes to organize the types:

Entry is a container that holds one of any JSON types at a time. If they're a primitive, it stores them. If they're an Array or Object, it stores a pointer to Array and Object containers.

Object containers hold a vector of their children as key value pairs.

Array containers hold their values as a vector of values.

Here's an overview of the containers. I've omitted most functions but you get the idea.

```
enum EntryType { 
  objectType, 
  arrayType,    
  stringType, 
  boolType,     
  intType,      
  doubleType,   
  nullType      
};

class Entry {
private:
  EntryType type;
  Object* objectEntry;
  Array* arrayEntry;
  std::string stringEntry;
  bool boolEntry;
  int intEntry;
  double doubleEntry;

public:
  void setType(EntryType);
  void setObject(Object*);
  Object* getObject() const;
  etc..
};

class Object {
private:
  std::vector<std::pair<Entry*, Entry*>> KVPair;
public:
  std::vector<std::pair<Entry*, Entry*>> getKVPair();
  etc...
};

class Array {
private:
  std::vector<Entry*> entryArray;
public:
  std::vector<Entry*> getArray();
  etc...
};
```

To give an example, after parsing the JSON string:

```
{"menu": {
"id": "file",
"value": "File",
"popup": {
  "menuitem": [
    {"value": "New", "onclick": "CreateNewDoc()"},
    {"value": "Open", "onclick": "OpenDoc()"},
    {"value": "Close", "onclick": "CloseDoc()"}
   ]
  }
}}
```

I begin with a vector of the outermost Objects (contained in Entry*'s). In this case, there's only one, so popping off that vector I get:

```
Entry*    //EntryType == objectType
```

representing the outermost object in the JSON:

```
{}
```

Getting the Object* from the entry returns a vector of key value pairs as entries, in this case with only one

```
std::pair<Entry*,Entry*>   //EntryType == stringType, EntryType == objectType
```

Where the first Entry* holds the Object's key "menu" and the second Entry* holds the object's value Object*, which is the next child object:

```
"menu" : {}
```

Thus, I map this pair and get the contents of the Object* which is a vector of key value pairs,

```
std::pair<Entry*,Entry*> //EntryType == stringType, EntryType == stringType
std::pair<Entry*,Entry*> //EntryType == stringType, EntryType == stringType
std::pair<Entry*,Entry*> //EntryType == stringType, EntryType == objectType
```

which represents:

```
"id": "file",
"value": "File",
"popup": {}
```

so I map the Entry*'s and denest the next object and so on and so on... As simple as it sounds, the project structure is very convoluted and I'm struggling to determine an algorithm that can do this.